# Rhythmbox menu to import music is missing

Tags: gnome, 20.04, gnome-shell, rhythmbox

When I first installed Ubuntu and first opened Rhythmbox, there was a menu to import music available near the top of the application, but now that menu is gone and I cannot bring it back.

I'm unsure whether this is due to gnome menus, or what could be causing this. This my fourth attempt installing Ubuntu and when I encountered this exact issue previously, I was able to find a solution after an hour of searching, but since then I've lost that Firefox profile after another reinstall and cannot access that same search to find that solution.

The issue here: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/rhythmbox/-/issues/1668 is similar, but the options presented do not provide the fix.

The issue here: [How to return the menus to Rhythmbox in Ubuntu 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085883/how-to-return-the-menus-to-rhythmbox-in-ubuntu-18-10) is not quite what I'm experiencing, but is slightly similar and again, does not provide a fix.

[Screenshot of my Rhythmbox under Play Queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFkJU.png)

[Rhythmbox under Music](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpyvE.png)

[The available Views menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwuyV.png)

I've above provided screenshots of my Rhythmbox that show the issue. Near the top of the screen there should be an accessible menu that has just a few options, one of them being the option to Import music and it's missing.

This is a relatively fresh install of 20.04 and I did see the missing menu when I first opened Rhythmbox, but now I can no longer find it.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

**Edit:** I kept searching, but was never able to find that original solution, so I just uninstalled Rhythmbox from terminal and then reinstalled it again from terminal. The reinstall returned the Import menu options as well as "File" menu. The good, 'ole "turn it off and on again" to the rescue...

Answer (score 2):

So I found the issues thanks to reinstalling. It seems that there's a plugin installed *rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar*, which causes this issue.

Remove *rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar* then things worked out for me again. Looks a bit more ugly, but meh.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar
```

Comment: This is not a very satisfying solution, but alas it is the only solution I could find to bring back the ability to import music.